# How to get a principal with @AuthenticationPrincipal

Tags: spring-security

I make a project on Spring Security.
The teacher wants me to get a principal with @AuthenticationPrincipal

I have this controller,
what should I remake to insert @AuthenticationPrincipal?

```
 @Controller
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String showUser(Model model) {
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "users";
    }
}
```

My git:  https://github.com/anatoliy19/3.1.2.git

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public String showUser(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {        
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "users";
}
```

Line with User delete.